# Can not connect to Azure web site hosted at VM

Tags: http, azure, web

I deployed a web site into a Azure VM and did the following

- 1) Create a HTTP Endpoint with TCP protocol and port 80 (both
     internal and external) for the VM
- 2) configure the web site to be assigned with the internal IP
  assigned

I can browse to the site within the VM, but can not connect to it from external using either the DNS or the public VIP assigned by Azure. the browser said "can not connect to [vip]".

Have I missed any steps or any advice on how to trouble shoot this issue?

Comment: Have you configured exactly as shown here - http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/public-access-of-website-hosted-in-azure-windows-server-vm/. Also have you enabled Application Development features using Server explorer, or else ASP.Net pages might not be served from IIS. I do not think you need to configure web site with internal IP.

Comment: Yes, I actually followed that article when I was configuring VM, and have enable all ASP .net related roles, and it works if I browse it within the VM with localhost. You are right, the internal IP is not necessary, but it doesn't make a difference as well even I removed the internal IP configuration.

Comment: What kind of error you are getting when you are browsing the site outside the VM? Is it ASP.Net error? I never added any firewall rules for port 80, and still it works.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a "normal" VM and not a Cloud Service then you need to connect to the VM and open port 80 in the Windows Firewall directly on the machine as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, i found it is caused by the selection of "direct connect" at the Endpoint setting.
Untick it, it works...